# OpenCL white space influence private memory usage?

Tags: opencl

I know this sounds weird, but I noticed that by adding a blank line before my kernel declaration, the amount of private memory usage drops from 72 bytes to 36 bytes.

My kernel is:

```
__kernel void multby2(__global float* data, __global float* results) {                                                 
    size_t id = get_global_id(0);                                                                                      
    results[id] = data[id] * 2;                                                                                        
}
```

Note that the first line is blank.  Inquiry with `clGetKernelWorkGroupInfo` for `CL_KERNEL_PRIVATE_MEM_SIZE` returns different results depending on whether the first line is blank.  Is this normal?  Or is it a bug of OpenCL?

Extra information:
Kernel is built with the following flags:
`-cl-finite-math-only -cl-opt-disable`

About my system:

```
platform name: Apple
platform vendor: Apple
platform version: OpenCL 1.2 (Apr 25 2013 18:32:06)
device name: GeForce 9400M
device vendor: NVIDIA
```

I appreciate any comments on this issue!

**Update:**
Thanks DarkZeros for pointing out that if kernel is built without optimization, there could be unstriped private memory.  Removing the flag `-cl-opt-disable` seems to be the solution.

Comment: It could be a compiler issue related to the driver. But for me, the problem could be that you have disabled the optimizations. This leads to non optimized code from the compiler, that may still have unstripped private memory.

Comment: DarkZeros, you are right.  Without `-cl-opt-disable` flag, white space can no longer influence the amount of private memory used.

Comment: I will put is as the answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That behaviour is clearly non-logical for the compiler. However, since optimizations have been disabled the compiler does not have to produce optimal code. It only has to produce code that works properly.

The problem is solved by simple removing the flag to the compiler: `-cl-opt-disable`

Without that flag the compiler should produce optimal code. This way it will strip all the non used private memory down to 36bytes (or even less).